# How can I run a non-service EXE on Windows XP as a service that will always run and automatically restart?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-services, unison

I have an executable (unison.exe in server mode) that I wish to run as automatically starting service on a Windows XP machine. I've installed it using the instsrv.exe and anysrv.exe method (tools available within the RKTools pack from Microsoft) and yet the service does not seem to automatically start and/or persist.

Interestingly if i go into Administrative Tools>Services and "restart" the service, it works for a while (30 min?) then seems to die. I've configured the service so that it is set to automatically restart if there is an issue, so my best guess is that it "thinks" it is running .. but it's not running properly until I give it a kick.

Any advice on an alternative way to have Unison.exe run in server mode as a service on a WinXP machine?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have always been using the SC command. While the instsrv.exe is the GUI interface I found SC.EXE to be more reliable:

**Creating Services:**

***Adding Service*** (Note: Space between binpath= and "C:\ has to be there.

\sc.exe create "Service Name" binPath= "C:\Your Program.exe"

***Removing Service***
  \sc.exe delete "Service Name"

***Controlling Services:***

***Starting Service***
  \sc.exe start "Service Name"

***Pausing Service***
  \sc.exe pause "Service Name"

***Stoping Service***
  \sc.exe stop "Service Name"

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll try that and report back. Can I add options to the exe, i.e. "C:\Your Program.exe -socket 100"?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that

Comment: `sc` can only start exe that are designed as a service, not "normal exe".